# AngularJS: Using ui-router to change view in same page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to have a multiple view in the same page.

I want to use ui-router to change **independently** the content of a view.

I've illustrated it with this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ludocluba/8uebahc5/)

Each panel can change its view.
When I try to change a view of a panel it changes the view of others.

Comment: And why you need to use ui-router for this? how you will handle routes for each panel?

Comment: I want to know if it's possible.I know I can do this without using ui-router.

Comment: I would say that ui-routed is not for that purpose. You're trying to display 4 pages not views.